# Why doesn't my selector using :target work in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I followed the instructions I found online when using `:target`, but it's not working. When the first link is clicked, I want the background color and font color of `#div1` to change. When the second link is clicked, I want the border of `#div2` to change. But nothing changes when I click either of the links.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
a.div1:target {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

a.div2:target {
  border: 10px dotted green;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#div1" class="div1">First Link</a>
<a href="#div2" class="div2">Second Link</a>

<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:target` matches the element that is linked **to**, not the link itself.

```
div#div1:target {
    background-color: blue;
}
```